# FetchApi example with image instead of text

Tags: zeppos

FetchApi example (https://github.com/zepp-health/zeppos-samples/blob/main/application/2.0/fetch-api) retrieves and presents JSON data in a TEXT widget. How do I fetch eg. https://docs.zepp.com/img/logo.png and show it in an IMG widget (API level 2)?